# AT error code 38 when sending commands through java

Tags: java, serial-port, gsm, at-command, modem

EDIT: I tried running it on my desktop rather than my laptop and it worked? I don't know why it wasn't working on the laptop but any ideas welcome...

I've been trying to send a message using AT commands in a java program. When sending the command manually it seems to work fine, but when sending through java I get error code 38 (Network Is Out Of Order). However, when I type the command in manually and then use Java to send the message, it still works, so I think the problem is with the command string. Any suggestions?

```
        CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort) portId.open("Application", 5000);
        char ctrlz = 26;
        String creturn = "\r";
        port.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, 
        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        port.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

        OutputStream outputStream = port.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.flush();
        String command = "\rAT+CMGS=\"[PhoneNumber]\"" + creturn;
        String message = "This is a java message test" + creturn;
        String end = Character.toString(ctrlz);
        System.out.println(command);
        System.out.println(message);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        outputStream.write(end.getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        outputStream.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        port.close();
        outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Why does your command *start* and end with a carriage return? Try without the one at the start

Comment: That was something I added after to see if it helped, even without the carriage return at the beginning I got the same result